# Probability of events(n T-shirts)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

You have n T-shirts in your wardrobe, They have different colors and different qualities. The probability that a T-shirt in your wardrobe is white is $0.7$, the probability that it is cotton is $0.4$ and the probability that it is both white and cotton is $0.3$.
What is the probability that a randomly chosen T-shirt will be neither white nor cotton?

I have tried calculating $Pr[White|Cotton]$ which will be $\frac{0.3}{0.4}=0.75$ and $Pr[Cotton|White]$, which will be $\frac{0.75*0.4}{0.7}\approx0.43$

However, I think it is very easy and it should be $1-0.3=0.7$, but then why do I need the other information. Can someone help me with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not conditional probablity question just use formula for probablity of A union B and then find probablity of complement of A union B where A is White,B is cotton

Comment: Do you mean this formula: P(A U B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AՈB)?

Comment: Yes this formula only is sufficient to answer your question by taking just complement.